# Need to update a DataFrame in R from another DataFrame, colnames of one dataframe matches contents of other dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

This is my first question on this amazing site. Please excuse my ignorance.

I am trying to wrangle dataframe in R for data analysis.

My dataframe  df1` looks like-

```
| id |  features                            

| 1 |   Window, Door, House, Curtains       |

| 2 |   Window, AirConditioner, GasStove    |

| 3 |   GasStove, Parking, Curtains         |

| 4 |   Curtains, Cable, Window             |
```

I've successfully create another dataframe by splitting texts-

```
s <- strsplit(df1$features, split = ",")
df2  <- data.frame(id = rep(df1$id, sapply(s, length)), features = unique(unlist(s)))
```

Now, `df2` looks like -

```
id| features

|1| Window

|1| Door

|1| House

|1| Curtains

|2| Window

|2| AirConditioner

|2| GasStove

|3| GasStove

|3| Parking

|3| Curtains

|4| Curtains

|4| Cable

|4| Window
```

I've also created all these UNIQUE columns in df1 dataframe such as - Window, Door, House etc.

I'd like my final dataframe `df3` to look like below -

```
|ID|Window| Door    |House  |Curtain    |AirConditioner| GasStove|  Parking |Cable|

 |1|    1   |1          |1      |1          |0             |0        |0         |0

|2| 1   |0  |0  |0  |1      |1  |0  |0

|3| 0   |0  |0  |1  |0      |1  |1  |0

|4| 1   |0  |0  |1  |0      |0  |0  |1
```

The values may be True (1) or False (0).

In short, what I need is, `df2`'s feature column contains "names" of `df3`'s columns, those columns needs to be populated with True/False (or 1/0).

Despite many attempts, I am unable to produce this.

I would appreciate your inputs.

I could use above in Python with `chain.from_iterable` But having trouble implementing it in R.

Comment: Hi Vinay, welcome to SO! It will be easier for others to help if you add your data using `dput(df1)`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I will do it next time.

Answer (score 1):

If you were willing to accept a solution using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
  separate_rows(features, sep = ', ') %>% 
  mutate(logical = 1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = features, values_from = logical) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0)


#> # A tibble: 4 x 9
#>      id Window  Door House Curtains AirConditioner GasStove Parking Cable
#>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>          <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1      1     1     1        1              0        0       0     0
#> 2     2      1     0     0        0              1        1       0     0
#> 3     3      0     0     0        1              0        1       1     0
#> 4     4      1     0     0        1              0        0       0     1
```

Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), features = c("Window, Door, House, Curtains", 
                                                "Window, AirConditioner, GasStove", "GasStove, Parking, Curtains", 
                                                "Curtains, Cable, Window")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                 -4L))
```

EDIT: The above code skips `df2`, but if you preferred to generate it here is one solution. Note I removed the `unique` from `features = unlist(s)` in `df2`.

```
s <- strsplit(df1$features, split = ", ")  
df2  <- data.frame(id = rep(df1$id, sapply(s, length)), features = unlist(s))

df3 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(logical = 1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = features, values_from = logical) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and input. When I run the code you'd suggested above, it generates error -
Error: Can't convert from <character> to <factor<018c4>> due to loss of generality.

Comment: I just reran and it works on my machine (R v4.0.2 and Tidyverse 1.3.0). Did you try with the `df1` as I suggested it? As a guess, it might be that your `df1` looks different than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option

```
df3 <- reshape(
  cbind(df2, X = 1),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "id",
  timevar = "features"
)
df3 <- replace(df3,is.na(df3),0)
```

which gives

```
   id X.Window X.Door X.House X.Curtains X.AirConditioner X.GasStove X.Parking
1   1        1      1       1          1                0          0         0
5   2        1      0       0          0                1          1         0
8   3        0      0       0          1                0          1         1
11  4        1      0       0          1                0          0         0
   X.Cable
1        0
5        0
8        0
11       1
```